# Bootstrap - Make a dropdown out of navbar-brand that is like navbar-collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, pug

I'm trying to turn my navigation bar's header into something just like the navbar collapse that already exists in Bootstrap. I've managed to turn the header into a dropdown, which will span just one line. Once completed, I want it to look like (but of course, much nicer):

```
 LINK / LINK / LINK / LINK       X(close)
```

Across one bar that, when the user clicks, will pop up like it does when on mobile (this will do it on mobile and on desktop). I hope this makes some sort of sense.

Once I hit the dropdown part, I started fiddling with the LESS, but managed to get nowhere, so I'm stumped.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
  body
    nav.navbar.navbar-default(role='navigation')
      .container
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
          div.dropdown
            a.navbar-brand.dropdown(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
              | Title
                    span.caret
            ul.brand-dropdown.dropdown-menu(role='menu')
              li
                a(href=route.auth('custservice')) Customer Service
              li
                a(href=route.auth('help')) Help

        .navbar-collapse.collapse
          form.navbar-form.navbar-left(role='search')
            .inner-addon.left-addon
              a.fa.fa-search.fa-lg(href='', type='submit')
              input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Search')
          block nav
              ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                li
                  a= auth.user().first_name
                li
                  a.fa.fa-shopping-cart.fa-2x(href=route.auth('cart'))
```

The only LESS I have does not matter for this, so it's completely care other than that. I'd love the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if anyone is looking for an answer for this, but I found that while you can make it into a dropdown, it will not mend seamlessly into the bootstrap layout. So, for those looking into it: I do not recommend it, it will not look as nice.